# How to merge specific rows that match a grep pattern

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Jen    Rptname   freq

 AKT      bilb1      23
 AKT      bilb1      234
 DFF      bilb22     987
 DFF      bilf34     7
 DFF      jhs23      623
 AKT      j45        53
 JFG      jhs98      65
```

I know how to group the whole dataframe based on individual columns but how do I merge individual rows based on a grep (in this case bilb.* and jhs.*)

I want to be able to merge the rows (and therefore also add the frequencies together) with bilb* and separately the rows with jhs* so that I end up with

```
   AKT      bilb       257
   DFF      bilb      987
   DFF      bilf34     7
   DFF      jhs       623
   AKT      j45        53
   JFG      jhs      65
```

This is so that the aggregation is by Jen and Rptname so I can see how many of the same Rptnames are in each Jen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep` to get the index of 'Rptname' elements that have 'bilb' or 'jhs', remove the numeric part with `sub` and use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'Freq' by 'Rptname'

```
indx <- grep('bilb|jhs', df1$Rptname)
df1$Rptname[indx] <- sub('\\d+', '', df1$Rptname[indx])
aggregate(freq~Rptname, df1, FUN=sum)
#   Rptname freq
#1    bilb 1244
#2  bilf34    7
#3     j45   53
#4     jhs  688
```

#### Update

Suppose your dataset is 'df2'

```
 df2$grp <- gsub("([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)[^A-Z]+", "\\1", df2$Rptname)
 aggregate(freq~grp+Jen, df2, FUN=sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Rptname = c("bilb1", "bilb1", "bilb22", 
 "bilf34", 
"jhs23", "j45", "jhs98"), freq = c(23L, 234L, 987L, 7L, 623L, 
53L, 65L)), .Names = c("Rptname", "freq"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df2 <- structure(list(Jen = c("AKT", "AKT", "AKT", "DFF", "DFF", 
"DFF", 
"DFF", "DFF", "DFF", "AKT", "JFG", "JFG", "JFG"), Rptname = c("bilb1", 
"bilb1", "bilb22", "bilb22", "bilb1", "BTBy", "bilf34", "BTBx", 
"jhs23", "j45", "jhs98", "BTBfd", "BTBx"), freq = c(23L, 234L, 
 22L, 987L, 18L, 18L, 7L, 9L, 623L, 53L, 65L, 19L, 14L)), 
.Names = c("Jen", 
"Rptname", "freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: OK I didnt realise but apparently there is a third column as well called Jen. I will amend the question to reflect this but I suspect this is why Im getting the error Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, indx, value = c(1L, 14L, 118L, 123L, 342L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated    after I use the line  df1$Rptname[indx] <- sub('\\d+', '', df1$Rptname[indx])

Comment: @user3632206 The `Rptname` column I used was `character` class.   It is better to work with 'character' columns.  You could read the dataset with `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to avoid columns getting converted to 'factors'.

Comment: Also the other point is that some of the groups I want to create dont just have numeric endings. Sometimes they end in different letters. I s there a way of accomodating this. eg BTBx and BTBy and BTBfd

Comment: @user3632206 Your new expected result is confusing. `bib1` is grouped as `bilb` while `bilb22` remains as such, which was not the same in the description, Or is it based on the other grouping variable?  It is better to create an example that mimics your whole dataset so that it can be coded at once.

Comment: @user3632206 Also, the new expected result based on the example can be got by `aggregate(freq~Jen+Rptname, df2, FUN=sum)`

Comment: @user3632206 If you check the results of `aggregate(freq~Jen+Rptname, df2, FUN=sum)`, it is almost the same as your expected result except some names i nthe `Rptname`.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to akrun's and I like his use of `aggregate` better than my creation of an intermediate vector:

```
> inter <- tapply(dat$freq, sub("^(bilb|jhs)(.+)$", "\\1", dat$Rptname) ,sum)
> final <- data.frame( nams = names(inter), sums = inter)
> final
         nams sums
bilb     bilb 1244
bilf34 bilf34    7
j45       j45   53
jhs       jhs  688
```

My pattern would require that the 'bilb' amd 'jhs' be at the beginning of the value. Remove the `"^"` if that was not intended, but if so, add a `"(.*)"` and switch to `"\\2"` in the replacement.