# how to grep text and aggregate

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
   Names            Sum
   Devpar - 1       10
   Devpar - 2       10
   Gadhashisha - 1  15
   Gadhashisha - 2  15
   Gadhashisha - 3  15
   Mau Moti - 1     20
   Mau Moti - 2     20
   Makda            10
```

I want to remove the numbers in `Names` column and add the sum.
My desired dataframe would be

```
   Names            Sum
   Devpar           20
   Gadhashisha      45
   Mau Moti         40
   Makda            10
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: This is the same, except that you need a different regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476615/how-to-merge-specific-rows-that-match-a-grep-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to remove the suffix part from the first column and then do the `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Names = str_remove(Names, "\\s+-\\s+\\d+")) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Sum))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Names         Sum
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 Devpar         20
#2 Gadhashisha    45
#3 Makda          10
#4 Mau Moti       40
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Names = c("Devpar - 1", "Devpar - 2", "Gadhashisha - 1", 
"Gadhashisha - 2", "Gadhashisha - 3", "Mau Moti - 1", "Mau Moti - 2", 
"Makda"), Sum = c(10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 10L)), .Names = c("Names", 
"Sum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I am getting following error `Evaluation error: could not find function "str_remove"`

Comment: @Neil it is `stringr`. library(stringr)

Comment: @Neil Which is the stringr version?  I have 1.3.1

Answer (score 3):

A base R version could be, Assuming df1 is the name of your dataframe :

```
df1$NewName <- gsub("(.*)\\s+(-.*)","\\1" ,df1$Names)
aggregate( Sum ~ NewName, data=df1, sum)

#       NewName Sum
#1      Devpar  20
#2 Gadhashisha  45
#3       Makda  10
#4    Mau Moti  40
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) base** Using only base and assuming the input `DF` is as shown reproducibly in the Note at end we remove the suffixes, compute the sums and remove redundant rows.  In r-devel (R 3.6) we could optionally replace the `sub(...)` in the first line of code with `trimws(Names, "right",  "[- 0-9]"))` .

```
DF0 <- transform(DF, Names = sub(" - .*", "", Names))
unique(transform(DF0, Sum = ave(Sum, Names, FUN = sum)))
```

giving:

```
           Names Sum
1         Devpar  20
2    Gadhashisha  45
3       Mau Moti  40
4          Makda  10
```

The code above maintains the original row order (as in the output requested in the question) but if sorted output were wanted then replace the last line of code above with:

```
aggregate(Sum ~ Names, DF0, sum)
```

**1a)** Using magittr (1) can be written as follows:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
   transform(Names = sub(" - .*", "", Names),
             Sum = ave(Sum, Names, FUN = sum)) %>%
   unique
```

**2) sqldf**   Using SQL we could express this as follows.   It gives the same answer as in #1. Omit the `order by` clause if the original order is not required or replace it with `order by 1` if sorted order is wanted.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select rtrim(Names, '- 0123456789') Names, sum(Sum) Sum 
       from DF 
       group by 1 
       order by rowid")
```

**3) data.table** This is also easy to do in data.table and returns the rows in the same order as in the question:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, list(Sum = sum(Sum)), by = sub(" - .*", "", Names)]
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Names,            Sum
   Devpar - 1,       10
   Devpar - 2,       10
   Gadhashisha - 1,  15
   Gadhashisha - 2,  15
   Gadhashisha - 3,  15
   Mau Moti - 1,     20
   Mau Moti - 2,     20
   Makda,            10"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following oneliner with base R:

```
aggregate(Sum ~ Names, transform(df1, Names = sub(' -.*','',Names)), sum)
```

The result:

```
        Names Sum
1      Devpar  20
2 Gadhashisha  45
3       Makda  10
4    Mau Moti  40
```